# How can I derive an output type for the template function?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I am confused with my template-based multiplication function with two inputs and a type that needs to be derived. How should I derive a type of a function?

```
template<typename T, typename U>
DERIVED_TYPE multiply(T t, U u) {
    return t * u;
}
```

Well, I know that `auto` or `decltype(auto)` does the work quite well, but I would like the other way if I can, studying is one reason. For example, with Eigen,

```
DERIVED_TYPE multiply(Matrix<int, 2, 3> t, Matrix<double, 3, 4> u) {
    return t * u;
}
```

the `DERIVED_TYPE` should be `Matrix<double, 2, 4>` of course.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you provide an example of "the other way"? The case for Eigen doesn't work because `decltype(t*u)` doesn't return a matrix but an expression template.

Comment: @JesperJuhl maybe that's the answer what I want!
I had no idea to derive the type except `auto`.

Comment: The effect you want is possible but nontrivial. Effectively, you will have to re-implement `auto`.

Comment: Use modern C++, and declare the template function as returning `auto`. Problem solved.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik no, doesn't work for Eigen. It returns expression templates.

Comment: This is C++. Not Eigen.

Comment: To do what you want without using `decltype` and/or `auto`, you would add public members to the `Matrix` class to expose the relevant typenames and parametric values of the `Matrix` instantiation. This is how they used to do it before C++11.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yes, this is C++, and OP use case is for Eigen, so you have to take that into account as well.

Comment: Don't make your solution worse than the problem. It may be easier to just not use your template function at all. In other words, you are really over complicating things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case:

```
DERIVED_TYPE multiply(Matrix<int, 2, 3> t, Matrix<double, 3, 4> u) {
    return t * u;
}
```

you can use [`std::common_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type) to derive the common type of `double` and `int`:

```
Matrix< std::common_type<int,double> , 2 , 4>
```

In general:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, size_t m,size_t n,size_t p>
Matrix< std::common_type<T1,T2>, m,p> multiply( Matrix<T1,m,n>, Matrix<T2,n,p>) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher thanks, removed that comment, I read the question to be about the general case and for learning purpose, the fact that `Matrix * Matrix` does not return a `Matrix` is relevant but not too much imho

Comment: Your solution requires a specialisation for `Eigen::Matrix<>`, while it is straightforward to provide a single definition for all types `T` and `U`.

Comment: @Walter I dont really understand what you are saying, though anyhow there is no reason to write that code in the first place, you'd simply write `auto x = a * b;`, its just meant for demonstration

Comment: @Walter OP: "Well, I know that auto or decltype(auto) does the work quite well" they explicitly asked for the long-winded cumbersome way

Comment: Oops. I (obviously form my answer) didn't see that. How strange. Nonsense question, in particular since tagged C++17.

Answer (score 3):

In C++11, you can use the operation itself to define the return type via the [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) specifier in conjunction with the [`auto`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) specifier

```
template<typename T, typename U>
auto multiply(T const &t, U const &u) -> decltype(t * u)
{
    return t * u;
}
```

In C++14 you can omit the trailing return type in the [function declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function)

```
template<typename T, typename U>
auto multiply(T const &t, U const &u)
{
    return t * u;
}
```

In C++20 you can omit the `template` specifier and use the [abbreviated function template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Abbreviated_function_template) syntax

```
auto multiply(auto const &t, auto const &u)
{
    return t * u;
}
```

Btw, I have made the arguments `const &` to avoid copies of large types.