# Automatic deduction of type of added array

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I am quite new to c++ and I try to create an Array class in c++17 with the use of templates. In this class I overload the + operator, in such a way that it can add Arrays of multiple types.  It does work so far and I am able to add arrays of different e.g. float and int type together. However, I am having some trouble with how to define the type of the new array, which is the result of the addition.

Let's say the arrays which I add are of type float and int. Then the new array should also be float. However, on forehand I dont know which array has the float type, the first one or the second one, so I can't create a new array with typename T or U.

Also, if due to coindicdence two float arrays add up together to only int values (e.g. 1.5 + 3.5 = 5(int) ), then the new array should be of type int.

Basically in summary, I try to define the type of the new array based on the type of the content after addition.

I came across some solutions that include decltype. However I can't manage to find a way how to include this for multiple values, since the array has more than one value. In my current code I create the new array based on the type T. However, if in a case T is of type int and U of type float, the result is not correct.

Any advice or tips are much appreciated.
Thanks in advance,

```
template <typename T>
class Array {
 public:
  T* content;
  int length;

  // Default Constructor
  Array() : content(nullptr), length(0) {}

  // Constructor when length is provided
  Array(int length) : content(new T[length]), length(length) {}

  // Constructor (using initializer list)
  Array(std::initializer_list<T> list) : Array((int)list.size()) {
    std::uninitialized_copy(list.begin(), list.end(), content);
  }

  // Obtain content at index i
  float& operator[](int i) { return content[i]; }

  // Adding arrays
  template <typename U>
  Array& operator+(Array<U>& other) {
    Array<T>* new_array = new Array(other.length);

    for (auto i = 0; i < other.length; i++)
      new_array->content[i] = this->content[i] + other.content[i];

    return *new_array;
  }
};
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54635703/how-can-i-derive-an-output-type-for-the-template-function/54635805#54635805

Comment: [`std::common_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type).

Comment: *"two float arrays add up together to only int values"* Return type cannot depend of resulting **value**.

Comment: @BoBTFish: with integral promotion and user defined operator, `decltype` seems more appropriate.

Comment: btw you have way too many `new` in your code, your eg your `operator+` is not returning what one would expect, dont throw `new`ed instances at your users, this will lead to memory leaks

Comment: `float& operator[](int i)` should be `T& operator[](int i)`.

Comment: Thanks all for the advice, I learn a lot like this.

Answer (score 1):

With `decltype`, your `operator +` might look like:

```
template<typename U>
auto operator+(const Array<U>& rhs)
-> Array<std::decay_t<decltype((*this)[0] + rhs[0])>>
{
    Array<std::decay_t<decltype((*this)[0] + rhs[0])>> res(rhs.length);

    for (auto i = 0; i != rhs.length; i++) {
        res[i] = (*this)[i] + rhs[i];
    }
    return res;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ae20118368c885d9)

Comment: Hi Jarod, thanks for your advice. I used your code and obtained the following error when I tried to add arrays of different types:  ERROR 1: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘Array<int>’ and ‘Array<float>’)
     a1+b1; ERROR 2: error: passing ‘const Array<float>’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
 -> Array<std::decay_t<decltype((*this)[0] +other[0])>>. Do you have an idea what I could be doing wrong here?

Comment: You should have `T& operator[](int i)` and `const T& operator[](int i) const`.

Comment: Thanks again for the advice. I implemented this and unfortunately this resulted in another error: error: no matching function for call to ‘Array<float>::Array(Vector<float>&)’
     return _res_ . I find it strange that _res_ is seen as a function.

Comment: Do you have copy/move constructor ? Does copy constructor take const argument ?

Comment: Yes I have  copy constuctor which takes a constant other vector as input. In addition I have a copy assinment operator and move assignment operator

Comment: Demo Links provided, and typos fixed.

Comment: Is it correct that in the + operator the copy constructor is called, which does not have a function 'res', which gives the error? If so, what would be a good method to avoid this?

Comment: Before C++17, move or copy constructor should exist (even if not called) and (unless NRVO) would be call. With C++17, construction is done in place, move/copy constructor are not even required.

Comment: Hi Jarod. Thank you very much for the explanation and effort. It helps a lot. If for some reason I do want a move/copy constructor, is there a possibility to fix the above error or is it required that these constructors are left out?

Comment: Other [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f0a1f5f6a30aaa38) with manual memory management.

Comment: Many thanks, by problem was I was still using the explicit copy constructor